# Seeking more information regarding the function $\varphi(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n \left[\binom{n}{i} \prod_{j=1}^i(i-j+1)^{2^j}\right].$

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, reference-request, semigroups, monoid

Define a function $\varphi : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ as follows.

$$\varphi(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n \left[\binom{n}{i} \prod_{j=1}^i(i-j+1)^{2^j}\right]$$

The motivation is that according to [this](http://u.math.biu.ac.il/~margolis/Representation%20Theory%20Seminar/Probability%20and%20Semigroup%20Representations/Semigroups%20and%20Ring%20Theoretic%20Methods%20in%20Probability.pdf) article, we have: for all natural $n$, $\varphi(n)$ is the cardinality of the free [band](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_%28mathematics%29) on $n$ generators.

> **Questions.**
>
> I'd like to learn more about $\varphi$.
>
> **Q0.** Does it have a standard name?
>
> **Q1.** Are there other, apparently unrelated counting problems to which $\varphi$ is the solution?
>
> **Q2.** Does $\varphi$ satisfy any interesting identities?
>
> **Q3.** If so, is there a good resource for learning these identities?

*Remark.* This function helps explain where the number $14$ comes from in the [Kuratowski closure-complement theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski%27s_closure-complement_problem). Basically, this happens because $$2(\varphi(2)+1) = 2(6+1) = 14.$$

To see the relevance of $\varphi(2),$ note that if $X$ is a topological space, then letting $k_X$ and $i_X$ denote the closure and interior operators on $X$ respectively, then the semigroup $S_X$ generated by $\{k_X,i_X\}$ is a band; furthermore, we can choose $X$ appropriately (e.g. $X = \mathbb{R}$) such that $S_X$ is the free band on these two elements.

Comment: The sequence is registered in OEIS. It has the number [A030449](https://oeis.org/A030449). It seems like that there is no evident research about the sequence.

Comment: The original reference is [1] Green, J. A. Rees, D. On semi-groups in which $x^r=x$, Proc. Cambridge Philos. Soc. 48, (1952) 35-40. Another proof can be found in [2] Lallement, Gérard. Semigroups and combinatorial applications. Pure and Applied Mathematics. A Wiley-Interscience Publication. John Wiley & Sons, New York-Chichester-Brisbane, 1979. xi+376 pp. ISBN: 0-471-04379-6, pp 300-302

Comment: The value of $\varphi(n)$ is better understood if you analyse the $\mathcal{J}$-structure of the free band with $k$ generators. The $\mathcal{J}$-classes are indexed by subsets of $\{1, \ldots, k\}$. The $\mathcal{J}$-classes indexed by subsets of size $j$ all have the same size $c_j$, where $c_1 = 1$ and $c_j = j^2c_{j-1}^2$.