# What is the maximum length of a non-repeating word on $n$ letters?

Tags: combinatorics

Let $X$ denote a set and $F_{\mathbf{Mon}}X$ denote the free monoid on $X$.

Call a word $w \in F_{\mathbf{Mon}}X$ *non-repeating* iff for all words $x,y,z \in F_{\mathbf{Mon}}X,$ we have:

$$w = xy^2 z \rightarrow y = 1$$

For example, if $X = \{a,b\}$, then the non-repeating words in $F_{\mathbf{Mon}}X$ are:

$$\{1,a,b,ab,ba,aba,bab\}$$

It turns out that if $X$ is finite, then $F_{\mathbf{Mon}}X$ has only finitely-many non-repeating words. Therefore, it has one or more non-repeating words of maximum length.

> **Question.** Suppose $X$ is a finite set, $n$ is a natural number, and $|X|=n.$ In terms of $n$, what is the maximum length of a non-repeating word in $F_{\mathbf{Mon}}X$?

More briefly: what is the maximum length of a non-repeating word on $n$ letters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are commonly called squarefree words (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_word). With three letters, they can be arbitrarily long.
One source for this result is a paper of Baake, Elser, and Grimm: *The Entropy of Square-Free Words* (http://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/9809010). From this paper, you can track down the original proof if you like, but I believe it may be due to Thue, and in German.

A construction that I found in *Avoiding and Enforcing Repetitive Structures on Words*, the 2014 dissertation of Mike Müller:

Let $h(0) = 0121$, $h(1) = 032$, $h(2) = 013$, and $h(3) = 0302$. Then $h^{(n)}(0)$ is squarefree for all $n$.

This is over four letters, but you can track down similar constructions for three letters from these sources (maybe even in Müller — I didn't read his entire dissertation).

Comment: It's hard for me to square (pun intended) what you're saying here with what I already know. In particular, [the free band on $n$ generators is finite](http://u.math.biu.ac.il/~margolis/Representation%20Theory%20Seminar/Probability%20and%20Semigroup%20Representations/Semigroups%20and%20Ring%20Theoretic%20Methods%20in%20Probability.pdf). But isn't there a natural bijection between squarefree non-empty words in $X$ and elements of the free band on $X$? (A band is an idempotent semigroup.)

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1474494/seeking-more-information-regarding-the-function-varphin-sum-i-1n-left?noredirect=1#comment3002897_1474494) also.

Comment: The existence of square-free words on a three-letter alphabet was proved by Axel Thue in the early 1900s. There is no contradiction with the fact that the free band on three generators is finite. See [Free idempotent semigroup with 3 generators](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1371255/free-idempotent-semigroup-with-3-generators) for more details.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Thank you for the link and clarification.

Comment: @eric-tressler You're welcome.